# regular expression all except few strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to allow all strings which matching a pattern but excluding few string following the same pattern

for example: select all string start with site: but not (site:dev or site:corp)
what I have is ...

site:.*[^!site:dev$][^!site:corp$]

this does not work if I test it for site:corps which is not exactly site:corp

can anyone help on this? [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cGZAlc/1)

Comment: Try [`site:(?!(?:dev|corp)$).+`](https://regex101.com/r/pH7jjI/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're using character classes []s when you should be looking at groups ()s.

Try something like this:    site:(?!(dev$|corp$))

Answer (score 0):

```
site:(?!dev)(?!corps).*
```

This uses two negative look-aheads (`(?! ...)`) after "site:".